# Does JOptionPane block Event thread

Tags: java, swing, thread-safety, joptionpane

My application is using `JOptionPane`s at some points for input of information.
At the same time that `JOptionPane` is shown, changes can happen on the GUI that are made from other clients over the network. These can be text on `JTextArea`, or nodes changing on `JTree`.

Does that mean that I need to create the `JOptionPane` on a new thread so that I will not have problems on the changes made during `JOptionPane` is active?

I looked on a few places on internet but I did not get a clear answer.

p.s `JOptionPane` is created when a user clicks on a button.

Comment: it doesn't really matter which thread you invoke JOptionPane in. It will be run in the UI thread

Comment: I did try it and there wasn't a problem, although it might be the case that there isn't 'always' a problem..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Swing is single threaded, so the option of 'using another thread' is simply not an option. However, that does not mean your components can not be updated while the option pane is shown. See below for an example. I added a System.out call to illustrate that the JOptionPane call is blocking, but due to the Swing timer I can append text to my JTextArea (on the EDT).

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class UpdateOptionPane {

  private static void showUI(){
    final JFrame testFrame = new JFrame( "TestFrame" );

    final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(  );
    testFrame.add( new JScrollPane( textArea ), BorderLayout.CENTER );

    Timer timer = new Timer( 1000, new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
        textArea.append( "bla" );
      }
    } );
    timer.setRepeats( true );
    timer.start();
    JButton button = new JButton( "Click me" );
    button.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
        System.out.println("Before option pane");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( testFrame, "A message dialog" );
        System.out.println("After option pane");
      }
    } );
    testFrame.add( button, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
    testFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    testFrame.pack();
    testFrame.setVisible( true );
  }

  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        showUI();
      }
    } );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me the Timer class I didn't know about it !

Answer (score 4):

JoptionPane is in reality a easy way to set up and use a JDialog. It sounds like what you want is a non-modal JDialog